# Нормализация пути

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

Есть путь `'C:/Users/babaykalopay/Desktop/test/test.bmp', 'All Files (*)'` Необходимо его нормализовать то есть убрать эту часть `, 'All Files (*)` .

Comment: Где есть? В переменной? В виде строки? В виде кортежа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с путями есть модуль os.path

```
import os
path = 'C:/Users/babaykalopay/Desktop/test/test.bmp', 'All Files (*)'
path, _ = path.split(',') # разделяем по запятой
path = path[1:-1] # уберем лишние кавычки
path = os.path.abspath(path) # нормализуем
print(path) # готово
```

Однако тут не совсем понятно у вас в исходных данных указан картеж. Если это так, то все еще проще

```
path = 'C:/Users/babaykalopay/Desktop/test/test.bmp', 'All Files (*)'
path = path[0]
path = os.path.abspath(path)
print(path)
```

Документация по модулю есть тут: [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Answer (score 1):

Если "путь" в вашем вопросе строка:

```
my_path = "'C:/Users/babaykalopay/Desktop/test/test.bmp', 'All Files (*)'"
normal  = my_path.split(", ")[0][1:-1]
```

Функция создает список `['C:/Users/babaykalopay/Desktop/test/test.bmp', 'All Files (*)']`, индекс `[0]` - его первый элемент (`'C:/Users/babaykalopay/Desktop/test/test.bmp'`) и `[1:-1]` уберёт из него первый и последний символ (апострофы).

---

Если "путь" в вашем вопросе списком, то только примените индекс `0`:

```
my_path = ['C:/Users/babaykalopay/Desktop/test/test.bmp', 'All Files (*)']
normal  = my_path[0]
```